# When to add eggs in brioche?

Tags: baking, bread

I'm working on a brioche recipe and have added my eggs after autolyse. I think the dough struggled to develop its gluten, though it eventually got there after a very long kneading time.

**Should I develop the gluten first (maybe to window pane), then add the eggs?** Or maybe I should add the eggs last, like I do with my fats (e.g. butter)?

I know sugar inhibits gluten development, so I add that after I've developed enough gluten. Maybe I need to add the eggs with the sugar?

Comment: What does your recipe tells you to do with the eggs?

Comment: what do you mean by autolyse?

Comment: Why are you doing an autolyse, and why are you trying to maximize gluten? Neither one is desirable in a brioche. And if your recipe doesn't tell you the process, ditch it.

Answer (score 1):

I combine wet ingredients first (milk with eggs) and then sugar, yeast and butter. Then whisk everything. After that, I add the flour and salt on top and mix by hand. I then let it rest for 30 mins before kneading so the flour absorbs all the wet ingredients. I hope this helps.